# Verify jwt token / Protected Routes NextJS NestJS andJWT

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, nestjs, token

I started to create an app, but I can't figure out something. I created my backend on Nest.js and frontend on Next.js . The authentication is created on the backend and is working fine. I did something on the frontend also to protect the routes that only a signed in user can see. It is working but if I set a fake token in my browser cookies, I can access those routes without signing in...

This is my login from the backend:
[image]

And this is how I protect my routes on Next.js (frontend):

```
const handleLogin = async (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.post<string>(
        "http://localhost:3003/auth/administrare-site", // Replace with your backend API endpoint
        formData
      );

      // Assuming your backend returns a token on successful login
      const token = response.data;

      // Store the token in local storage or a cookie for future requests
      Cookies.set("token", JSON.stringify(token), {
        expires: 7,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "strict",
      });


      // Redirect to the dashboard page
      router.push("/dashboard");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  };
```

this was the login on the fronend.
Here I have the middleware to protect the routes:

```
function requireAuth<T extends JSX.IntrinsicAttributes>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<T>
) {
  return (props: T) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    // Check if the 'token' cookie is present
    const tokenString = Cookies.get("token");
    let token = tokenString;


    console.log(token);
    if (!token) {
      // Redirect to the login page if the token is not present
      console.log('failed')
      router.push("/administrare-site");
      return null;
    }
   
    console.log('good')
    // Render the protected component if the token is present and valid
    return <Component {...props} />;
  };
}

export default requireAuth;
```

and here is it how I use the requireAuth to protect the routes:

```
export default requireAuth(Dashboard);
```

So the problem is that on frontend the token is not verified and I don't know how to do it without discovering my JWT_SECRET(not secured if I do this). Don't judge me, it's my first full stack app and I'll appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your JWT SECRET safe, you have to decode your JWT on server side. In front-end you just verify that token exists, so this is not enough.

You have to create an API controller on your Nest.js and pass the token from client to back-end and verify it, if it is true, redirect user from back-end to where you want, if it is not, delete the token and redirect user from back-end to signing in page.

You can do this in Next.js back-end also! The only thing you need is to verify token in Next.js backend and do the process as like I said.